# Updating a writable property in IOT Central via mqtt from device

Tags: mqtt, azure-iot-central

I was able to connect to IOT Cental via Mqtt, and update a read-only property from device to server, and writable property from server to device.

I am wondering if it is possible to update a writable property from device to server, and how the payload would look like?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqKKQ.png)

Comment: It should be very similar, if not exactly the same. Are you trying to update the value from the device AFTER the cloud has sent an update? If so, you'll need to include the version and a status code when responding. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-use-properties#implement-writable-properties?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034) have a sample, but not without the SDK though.

Answer (score 1):

The [IoT Plug and Play device developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-pnp/concepts-developer-guide-device?pivots=programming-language-csharp) described in details how to handle the telemetry, properties and commands in the device model. The simple case is when your model has only a default component.

The following example shows the major steps for updating a writeable property by device.

1. Creating a device template *abba* with a default component:
   [image]
2. Device *abba* with this template and its view *Pattern*:

   [image]
3. Simulated device *abba* using my [Azure IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester):

   [image]

   Note, that the versions are after few testing properties and then resetting to null.
4. Updating both properties such as *Reported* (read-only property) and *Desired* (writable property) by device:

   [image]
5. Showing the device twin on the device side:

   [image]
6. IoT Central App view panel:

   [image]

   As you can see the above screen snippet, the read-only property shows immediately the value, but the writable property is showing a pending prompt text. In this point, the *Desired* property is waiting for accepting this value. Basically there are two ways how to make it, such as:

   a. typing the value getting from the raw data or

   b. using the REST PUT request call, see the following screen snippet:

   [image]
7. IoT Central App view panel (updated):

   [image]

   Note, that the page must be refreshed manually, when the value has been accepted.

I do recommend to subscribe on the *devicePropertyDesiredChange* topic using the Data export features for receiving a notification on the changes, see an example of the message received in the Service Bus queue:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

In the case of using multiple components in your device model (at least one behind the default component), the following example shows how to update a writeable property in the component by device:

8. Creating a new version with a component *abc*:

   [image]
9. New version of the Pattern view:

   [image]
10. Simulated device *abba2* sent the update for writable property *Desired* at the component *abc*:

    [image]
11. IoT Central App shows a pending status:

    [image]
12. Cloud backend service received a notification message in the queue:

    [image]
13. Cloud backend service will sent an accepted request for this writable property, note, that the url address shows a path to the specific component:

    [image]
14. IoT Central App shows a new accepted *Desired* value in the view *Pattern* at the ComponentA such as *abc*:

    [image]

That's all. Using the above steps, any read-only and/or writable properties declared in the multiple components can be updated from the device side. Note, that the telemetry data outside of the default component are handling differently.